# Запятая перед союзом «хотя»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, союзы

> Я так и не полюбил Токио, хотя и побывал там четыре раза.

Это не сложное предложение, так как сказуемые относятся к одному подлежащему, но тогда почему они разделяются запятой перед союзом «хотя», ведь это уже получается сложноподчинённое предложение. Можете объяснить?

Comment: Перед противительным союзом всегда ставится запятая. Предложение из-за этого не становится сложным: *я бежал быстро, но недолго*, например.

Answer (score 2):

*Я так и **не полюбил** Токио, **хотя и побывал** там четыре раза.*

1. Это предложение с однородными сказуемыми. Как известно между однородным членами ставится запятая при бессоюзной связи, а также при наличии различных союзов. Исключением являются одиночные союзы И, ИЛИ, тогда запятая не ставится.
2. А что можно сказать **о союзе ХОТЯ И**. В данном случае это сочинительный союз, в то же время существует подчинительный союз с уступительным значением  ХОТЯ.
3. Члены ряда могут быть полностью равноправными, а могут быть семантически
   дифференцированными, т. е. могут характеризоваться **добавочным
   значением.** И вот  союз ХОТЯ И придает второму сказуемому уступительное значение.

**Примечание.** Дифференцировать отношения  могут  **частицы, наречия, модальные слова:** тем не менее, вместе с тем, одновременно, все-таки, все же, хотя бы, особенно, в особенности, тем более, может быть, главное, даже и др. Например: *Яблоки очень вкусные, **хоть и** не очень крупные.* *Он купается в озере летом, осенью **и даже** зимой.* *Я пошлю тебе письмо, **а может**, и телеграмму;*